# Swapping balls from two boxes

Tags: probability, expected-value

Imagine that there are two boxes A, B. Box A contains 10 blue balls and
box B contains 10 red balls. In every step, we pick one ball randomly
from box A and one ball randomly from box B at the same time, and
then swap them, i.e., we put the chosen ball from box A into box B, and
vice versa.
(a) What is the expected value of the number of blue balls in box A
after the second step?
(b) What is the expected value of the number of blue balls in box A
after the third step?

(a)
The probability of drawing a blue ball from box A and drawing a red ball from box B is: (9/10)*(9/10) = 81/100

Red ball from box A, Red ball from box B is (1/10)*(9/10) = 9/100
A blue ball from box A, and a blue ball from box B is (9/10)*(1/10) = 9/100

A Red ball from box A, a blue ball from box B is (1/10)*(1/10) = 1/100

E(x) = 8(81/100)+10*(1/100)+9*(9/100)+9*(9/100) = 8.2

(b) Following a similar method:
E(x) = 7.2*(67.24/100)+9.2*(3.24/100)+8.2*(14.76/100)+8.2*(14.76/100) = 7.56

Is my understanding of this question correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are correct, but since the questions are only about the blue balls in box A, if you think a bit,

in one transaction, the *expected* number of blue balls in box $1$ change from $B$ to $0.9B + 0.1(10-B) = 0.8B +1$

$\begin{align}\text{Thus}\;B_0&&&=10,\\
B_1&= 8+1&&=9, \\  
B_2 &= 7.2 + 1 &&= 8.2,\\  
B_3 &= 6.56 + 1 &&= 7.56\end{align}$

Comment: @Graham Kemp: Thanks for repairing a careless omission, and reformatting to mathematical precision.